# Apache log files, erase it, purge?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

my is newbie's question:

how can i set error.log file and all various logs to keep only few days of log? my files are huge now! i cant keep 20GB of just logs! i saw and increase of diskspace like form 30% to 110% in 5 days...
maybe i have a running process that creates a background error?
in any case is it pobbisle to limit of the size of those files??

how do you access those logs? 
i mean do you just use terminal to read them?
via webmin?

Answer (score 5):

You should set up logrotated to automatically rotate the logs round.

```
/var/log/apache2/*log {
        daily
        rotate 7
        create 777 apache apache
}
```

should get you going as a basic config (Put it in /etc/logrotate.d/httpd), that rotates the files round daily and keeps them for 7 days. There are lots of options available for logrotated (Like GZIP, rotate on size etc.)

And for reading them, normally you would use something like webalizer or AWStats to create a 'pretty' version of your logs.

Comment: Kind of - That should be 'create 644'. 'missingok' and 'notifempty' would be good too - also, you should tell apache to close and reopen the log file - '/sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true' (in a postrotate block)